# Visual studio 2015 NOT detecting Controllers and Models I added manually

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am new to Visual Studio and C#.

I created a MVC project project and named it let's say **XYZ**. It runs fine and contains two custom Controllers and 2 Models.

I then created another project I will call **XYZ2**. I copied the 2 controllers and 2 models from project XYZ in Windows Explorer `(manually from "Controllers" and "Models" folders respectively)`.

Now when I access **XYZ2** in Visual Studio the two files are **NOT** showing. What is wrong and what is the reasoning behind?

Comment: you need to add them to the project.

Comment: you need to add them to the project - right click on the project in sol explorer and say 'add existing item'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Visual Studio, open your solution and click here to show all files in the file system:

[image]

Then in the Solution Explorer, include the files in project (Right click the file -> Include In Project):

[image]

ALTERNATIVELY, you may right-click in your solution -> Add -> Existing Item and this will open a file explorer window where you can select the files you wish to add.